# Can I correct a bias, or “skew” in my data using linear regression?

Tags: r, regression, data-transformation, linear, bias-correction

My supervisor has suggested that I correct a bias, or "skew" in my data using linear regression. Apparently the line of fit in the plot below should be horizontal (example attachted)

Its a screening experiment, I am plotting the Z scores of my control condition, against the Z-difference between the test conditon and the control.

I can use the lm function to get a linear regression model of the data. But then do I use this function somehow to correct the y-axis data set? or should I be using a completely different set of tools? Any guidance would be useful.

I am not a mathematition or statistician so please don't presume too much knowledge, and thanks in advance.[image]